# Install Library and Its Dependencies From Maven Repository Into Internal Repository

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependencies, repository

### Question

I have an internal maven repository in a shared folder say `s:\mvnrepo` – it's just a convention for a directory layout after all. Now I want to install a library `com.example.lib:lib:1.0.0` **and its dependencies** from another external maven repository into `s:\mvnrepo` with the hypothetical command

```
mvn installlib com.example.lib:lib:1.0.0 -Dinto=file:///s:/mvnrepo
```

That would be a dream! Is such a thing possible?

<sup>(I don't have high hopes seeing as everything maven related is always so unapproachable and complicated...)</sup>

### Supplemental Information

Now, I know there are maven repository management systems like Nexus but I really do think my use case should not require them. I also know about the `deploy-file` goal but it doesn't install transitive dependencies into the specified repository.

I also thought about simply creating a dummy project that has the specific library listed in its `pom.xml`. Then just execute `mvn install -Dinto=file:///s:/mvnrepo`. The problem is that the install goal apparently does not have an [option](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-mojo.html) to specify the repository directory (i.e. `-Dinto` is purely hypothetical).

I found out that it is possible to [download a library and all its dependencies with Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/downloading-libraries-from-maven-repositories.html). That's great but Intellij really only downloads the jars and does not create a maven compatible directory structure (i.e. there are no poms downloaded nor are the jars in a group subfolder etc.).

#### Background information

For work we want to have an internal maven repository such that it is possible to build an application on a freshly installed server that does not have an internet connection while still being able to specifiy dependencies in the gradle file as if we would use an external maven repository like `jcenter` (resp. bintray). So the gradle file we use would look something like this:

```
repositories {
   // jcenter() // we don't want that
   mavenUrl 'file:///s:/mvnrepo'
}
dependencies {
  compile 'com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0'
}
```

Now, I downloaded the sdkmanager plugin jar and its pom file from [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.sdkmanager/gradle-plugin/0.12.0) and used something like

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dfile=sdkmanager.jar -Dpom=sdkmanager.pom -Durl=file:///s:/mvnrepo
```

All fine and dandy, the sdkmanager plugin is installed into `s:\mvnrepo` with the correct directory layout and gradle even picks it up! But gradle is not quite satisfied, you see. It demands the `jarchivelib` which is a dependency of `com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:gradle-plugin:0.12.0` (see the page on [mvnrepository.com](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.sdkmanager/gradle-plugin/0.12.0) where `jarchivelib` really is listed as a dependency of the sdkmanager plugin). Now, I could repeat the fun and download `jarchivelib` and its pom from mvnrepository.com, deploy it and so on. Thinking about it... that does not sound like fun at all! So now you see my concrete use case and maybe you could suggest an even better approach than what I seek for in my question.

Comment: This use case describes exactly the purpose of a repository manager like nexus.

Comment: @khmarbaise Eventually, Nexus is exactly what we ended up with. Still doesn't change the fact that the use case in my question could be supported, imho. I mean, it's not that absurd, is it. And the capability is already there—there's just no way to get at it through the command line interface it seems.